# jquery chosen leaves drop down list open in Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I am using the jQuery [Chosen plugin](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) to make select boxes more beautiful and searchable. For some reason it seems to not work properly; all options of the `select` box are visible on the page.

But on other pages the plugin seems to be working fine. I am not sure why this is happening on a particular page. I've tried all possible ways like removing other javascript, moving up and down but still no luck. Any directions on how I can resolve this issue?

Sample HTML block

```
<tr>
    <td class="right">Site: <span class="required">*</span></td>
    <td class="left">
        <select name="tkr.site.id" id="site_id_list" class="chzn-select" style="display: block;width:200px">
            #{list items:site_list, as:'site'}                  
                #{if tkr.site && site.id == tkr.site.id}
                    <option value="${site.id}"  selected>${site.name} (${site.shortname})</option>
                #{/if}  
                #{else}                     
                    <option value="${site.id}">${site.name}  ( ${site.shortname} ) </option>
                #{/else}
            #{/list}
        </select><br/>

        <span class="error">#{error 'tkr.site' /}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's the header where I include jQuery and Chosen plugins:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="screen"   href="@{'/public/stylesheets/jquery.treeview.css'}" type="text/css" />  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="@{'/public/stylesheets/comments.css'}">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="tdeext/css" media="screen" href="@{'/public/stylesheets/chosen.css'}">

<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="@{'/public/javascripts/chosen.jquery.js'}" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and javascript where iam calling chosen is

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

     $("form").submit(makeDateTimeProper);


     if ($("input[name=query]").length > 0 )
     {
         $("input[name=query]").corner();
         $("input[name=query]").focus();    
     }

     $(".chzn-select").chosen();



     var sdattime  = $("#content   input[name=tkr.startdatetime1]").val();
     var edattime  = $("#content   input[name=tkr.enddatetime1]").val();
```

Comment: Maybe you are calling it twice?

Comment: no iam calling only once

Comment: Can you please post the HTML and jQuery code you are using.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console log on that page?

Comment: @Morpheus no iam not getting any errors on console and in chrome it is working correctly in firefox,IE it is breaking.

Comment: Have you tried different version of jQuery?

Comment: Yes i have tried still the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but in case someone else has the same problem:
I experienced the same problem and the chosen selects stayed open all the time, no matter what I did .
I could solve it, after I replaced the bundled chosen.css with the version from git.
There seems to be a problem with some css versions of chosen

Answer (score 0):

Try {des pack plugins} is very complete.
http://des.delestesoft.com:8080/?go=7